# local host gives error 403 on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-2.2

Hello I am new to ubuntu linux and am currently trying to configure my netbeans to work with PHP. I have found several tutorials to install all the applications I need and have installed a virtual directory for netbeans to run in. Unfortunately, whenever netbeans or I myself go to my local host I get an error 403. I tried modifying my settings to allow from localhost (instead of allow from all) but this did not work and am completely out of ideas.

Comment: Look into the `error.log` file to see why access was denied. But this is probably better off on serverfault, voting to migrate there

Answer (score 2):

I had this error.  For me, it was because the web server was running under the user "apache" and it didn't have read permissions on the file it was trying to access -- try chown'ing the directory to "apache".